# my code throws TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, picamera

I'm trying to get the NDVI of a plant image. As probably you know this project is on the Internet and for me, it was working some years ago. Now that I am trying to use it again, I have a mistake in the last part of the process, here the complete code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from fastiecm import fastiecm
from picamera import PiCamera
import picamera.array

cam = PiCamera()
cam.rotation = 360
cam.resolution = (1920, 1088) # Uncomment if using a Pi Noir camera
stream = picamera.array.PiRGBArray(cam)
cam.capture(stream, format='bgr', use_video_port=True)
original = stream.array

def display(image, image_name):
    image = np.array(image, dtype=float)/float(255)
    shape = image.shape
    height = int(shape[0] / 2)
    width = int(shape[1] / 2)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (width, height))
    cv2.namedWindow(image_name)
    cv2.imshow(image_name, image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def contrast_stretch(im):
    in_min = np.percentile(im, 5)
    in_max = np.percentile(im, 55)
    
    out_min = 0.0
    out_max = 255.0
    
    out = im - in_min
    out *= ((out_min - out_max) / (in_min - in_max))
    out += in_min

    return out


def calc_ndvi(image):
    b, g, r = cv2.split(image)
    bottom = (r.astype(float) + b.astype(float))
    bottom[bottom==0] = 0.01
    ndvi = (r.astype(float) - b) / bottom
    return ndvi

display(original, 'Original')
contrasted = contrast_stretch(original)
display(contrasted, 'Contrasted original')
cv2.imwrite('contrasted.png', contrasted)
ndvi = calc_ndvi(contrasted)
display(ndvi, 'NDVI')
ndvi_contrasted = contrast_stretch(ndvi)
display(ndvi_contrasted, 'NDVI Contrasted')
cv2.imwrite('ndvi_contrasted.png', ndvi_contrasted)
color_mapped_prep = ndvi_contrasted.astype(np.uint8)
color_mapped_image = cv2.applyColorMap(color_mapped_prep, fastiecm)
display(color_mapped_image, 'Color mapped')
cv2.imwrite('color_mapped_image.png', color_mapped_image)
cv2.imwrite('original.png', original)
```

The mistake I am getting is:

```
 color_mapped_image = cv2.applyColorMap(color_mapped_prep, fastiecm)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I was reading that the mistake could be solved with `map()`, `list()` or `np.vectorized`, I was trying but I can imagine because of my lack of knowledge, I couldn´t get any result, please help me with my problem. Also, I think this project should be updated since it is for taking care of the plants. Thank you for your help.

I tried to use `list()`, `map()` and `np.vectorize`, also I tried to do another complete new code using `LUT`, but this did working before, and with `LUT` I don't get the results I need.

Comment: What is NDVI? Is that a common term? Not everyone understands plant imaging. Please define your terms or provide a reference.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastiecm'` -- [mre] required.

Comment: Hi @fmw42, thanks for your question. Here I give you the link in which you can find the complete project: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/astropi-ndvi

Comment: Hi Christoph Rackwitz, yes you need to download the Fastiecm file in the same place you save the project. Mainly as I understand, is the colour-numbers numpy uses for making the filter.